Cant bind Angular custom NPM package
Hi guys i have created my custom dynamic tooltip npm package but when I use that package in an app, I get this error
  Can't bind to 'appDynamicTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.<div class="class-tooltip" [appDynamicTooltip]="tooltipData" [tooltipConditions]="conditions">

Now this is a common angular error that we face when the imports are not correct but my import is just one module and it was successfully imported inside my app and I can view the module. what I'm trying to figure out is if there is something wrong with my package the way I'm exporting it maybe?.
Here is the GitHub link to my Package dynamic-tooltip
Here is how I have imported my Package


Your directive is missing @Input() appDynamicTooltip?: string;

Probably you should just change to @Input('appDynamicTooltip') tooltipData: any;

Thanks @Pieterjan this solved my issue i tried doing the same for the conditions as well but it didn't work, so I just combined the two inputs into one and did as u suggested now working fine. Feel free to put this as the answer I'll mark it as the answer. Once again Thanks. :)

You can just use both inputs <div [appDynamicTooltip]="'some tooltip'" [tooltipConditions]="[]">

No it doesn't work we get the same error for tooltipConditions as well. @Pieterjan

As Pieterjan mentioned in the comments this solved my issue @Input('appDynamicTooltip') tooltipData: any
I should denote the input within the directive with the selector from which i send the data
That is when i use the directive i should use it like this
[appDynamicTooltip]="tooltipData"
